# Android and SQLite - select everything between 2 datetime's

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

How can I select everything from an Android SQLite database that has DATETIME fields for a particular day?

I have created the following table:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "" +
            "create table " + TABLE_STATISTIC + " (" 
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " DATETIME default current_timestamp, "
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_SERVICED + " integer not null, "
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_CATEGORY + " integer); ";
```

As you can see, it has a DATETIME field. I need to fetch all data between DATETIME from the beginning of the day and end of the day.

How can this be done? I can't find out how to generate these values in java/android or directly in the SQL statement.

I really hope someone can answer this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It will be better that you save timeinmillies in db instead of datetime

Comment: I have done in my app here is my table
db.execSQL("create table UploadBillDataTable(_id integer primary key autoincrement,totalBill text, totalConsumption text, uploadBillDate integer ,unit text, uploadingMonth integer)");

Comment: check http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First save date in database in long format.

2.Then compare these date with start and end dates as follows

dbDate > startTime && dbdate < endTime

where startTime and endTime is range in which you want to fetch data

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I ended up with your suggested solution to save long values in the database instead of Datetime, which was a lot easier to work with. I'll accept your answer as I think you were the first to post it :)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have real date/time types but stores everything as strings. A string is accepted as a date in SQLITE if and only if it has a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

current_timestamp: This function also gets the current date time in the format given above.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_STATISTIC WHERE COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME BETWEEN '2014-01-01 13:42:03' AND '2014-03-20 13:42:03';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of options available on google if you do some more research on **between** clause
You can also try this

```
`SELECT * FROM DOB WHERE birthdate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;`
```

OR

```
SELECT Date,dob from pb where uid=1 and Date>'2011/02/25' and Date<'2011/02/27'
```

and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) will guide more.

Comment: are they tested query ?? i am sure it will not compare dates in sqlite

Comment: Now i dont tested that my self

Answer (score 0):

As the other people are saying, save the time in long.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "" +
            "create table " + TABLE_STATISTIC + " (" 
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " integer not null, "
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_SERVICED + " integer not null, "
              + COLUMN_STATISTIC_CATEGORY + " integer); ";
```

Then in your select

```
"Select * from " + TABLE_STATISTIC + " where " + COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " > " + startTime " AND " COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " < " + endTime + ";"
```

Add startTime and endTime into your function, these should be in millis

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution in your case, if you only want to get the date between specified number of days is to use date('now') function in SQL. So, i think this would be a better solution in your case

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_STATISTIC WHERE COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME BETWEEN DATE('now') and 
DATE('now','1 day')
```

And, in case if you want to compare considering localtime of the device you can use the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_STATISTIC WHERE COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME BETWEEN DATE('now','localtime') and DATE('now','1 day','localtime')
```